# Python Selenium webdriver returns a blank page when I try to get it, only for a specific URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to open the given URL below with Selenium in Chrome webdriver, browser just returns a blank, white page. When I enter the URL manually in a browser of my choice, I can open it and see the contents though.

I can enter to other websites, it is just this one that returns a blank page:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver')
driver.get("http://wolfscream.sozlukspot.com/")
```

This "sozlukspot.com" is a local Turkish website for creating little forums, I am trying to scrape a forum page here, but not only "http://wolfscream.sozlukspot.com/", none of these sozlukspot forums open with selenium.

What is the deal with this specific webpage? Why can't I open it in a Selenium Chrome webdriver? What to do in order to open this specific page? Thanks.

Comment: This might be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: It might be problem with the chromedriver. Yesterday I had similar problem and i fix it by switching to gecko (firefox)

Comment: `https://www.wolfspot.sozlukspot.com/` throws a security certificate error, and when you finally access the page it shows something like this: https://imgur.com/CVPC8Pi.png . Do you understand why I was suspicious firt time you asked this question?